# Can I check an Asana API key against some regular expression

Tags: asana

Can I check an API key against some regular expression, for example if I want to use it to on an input form?

Answer (score 0):

(I work at Asana)

No, we do not guarantee the format of an API key. Also, for security reasons, we discourage writing apps that solicit API keys from users. In the future we plan to improve our supported authentication mechanisms to make it easier for users to securely authenticate with apps  written by developers.

Comment: So is there a better way to access data of an individual user?

Comment: At the moment, no. But in the future we hope to support the Oauth2 authentication mechanism which will allow users to authorize apps to access and use data on their behalf.

Comment: Hi @GregS I'm working on integrating our app with asana. Are users allowed to authorize apps to access to use data on their behalf yet?

Comment: Not yet - we have not yet launched Oauth support, but when we do users will be able to grant your apps access to their data.